# What is the meaning of the expression "aller bon train" here?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> **Les querelles vont bon train** entre les différentes factions.

I usually associate the expression "aller bon train" with "les rumeurs" spreading freely or "les préparations" going smoothly, but what about its meaning when "aller bon train" is coupled with a noun such as "les débats" and "les querelles"?

Does it refer to the ***fierce*** nature of quarrels? Or is it more about quarrels happening ***frequently***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Aller bon train" means "going fast", "propagating fast". As "train" also means "speed".

The meaning is not relative to what you're talking about: so this is not "spreading freely" or "going smoothly", as far as I know.

The opposite is "aller son petit train"... which means "going slowly but quite surely".

A reference [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/train) or [here](https://www.littre.org/definition/train).

In complement, we also have "mener grand train" which can have the same meaning as "aller bon train" but which is more commonly associated to the "train de vie" (high quality of life, spending many money).

Comment: Hi. So how do you rephrase the example sentence in my question? :) The idea of quarrels *going fast* does not seem to make much sense...

Comment: Hi @Alone-zee, yes, that why I've also indicated "propagating fast".

Comment: Oh, so is it like: "What may have started off as an insignificant spat between two people snowballed into heated arguments involving increasing number of people"? Just like a small bonfire turning into a widespread uncontrollable fire engulfing an entire forest?

Comment: More or less, but with nothing meaning "something is growing": simply about the speed (fast). What you said in the last comment is more "s'emballer", "s'enflammer" (figurative sens): growing in importance or intensity.